# Error executing a perl command using popen in C++

Tags: c++, perl, popen

In my c++ program I want to execute a perl comand and read the output returned by the execution. I use popen for that, but I get an error when executing my command:

Command:

```
string cmd = "perl -ne 's/^\\S+\\s//; if ((/" +
            pattern1+ " START/ .. /" + pattern2+ " END/) && /find/)"
            " { print \"$_\"}' file";
stream = popen(cmd.c_str(),"r");
```

If I execute this command in the command line it works, but in C++ i get this error:

```
Search pattern not terminated at -e line 1.
```

The command that works in command line is, in C++ I already escaped the '\' and '"':

```
perl -ne 's/^\\S+\\s//; if ((/aaa START/ .. /bbb END/) && /find/) { print "$_"}' file
```

If I execute this command, it works: "perl -ne print $_ file".
But my initial command doesn't.
What I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: If you `cout` that string does it look like you expect?

Comment: Yes it look how I want, and If I copy paste the printed command in terminl it works.

Comment: I don't think it does, see the missing slashes in my example

Comment: What does `file` look like?

Comment: It worked at command line to execute that command. So the command is good.

Comment: If I deleted "s/^\\S+\\s//;" the command worked from c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your escape characters `\`.  You'll have to double them up in the C++ string as `\\` gets turned into `\`.  Then the shell does it's processing as you see on the command line.  i.e. another round of `\\` turned into `\`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your backslashes (by adding more backslashes!).

```
std::string cmd = "perl -ne 's/^\\\\S+\\\\s//; if ((/" +
                  pattern1 + " START/ .. /" + 
                  pattern2+ " END/) && /find/)"
                  " { print \"$_\"}' file";
```

In C++0x you can use raw `R"(strings)"` to avoid adding slashes. Compile with GCC like

```
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall popen.cpp
```

example:

```
std::string cmd_raw = R"(perl -ne 's/^\\S+\\s//; if ((/)" +
                      pattern1 + R"( START/ .. /)" + 
                      pattern2 + R"( END/) && /find/))"
                      R"( { print \"$_\"}' file)";
```

Comment: But if I run in the cmd, the first line of your output works. And that is the command I used. If I use R i get error: cmd not found. Thanks.

Comment: I already escaped the characters in my c++ command. I edited my post and put the command that works in the command line and need to be translated in c++.

Comment: I can not add -std=c++0x to use R() function. I can not edit the makefile's project.

Comment: @georgiana_e in that case you have no choice but to use the backslash option

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
cmd = "perl -ne 's/^\\\\S+\\\\s//; if ((/" +
            pattern1+ " START/ .. /" + pattern2+ " END/) && /find/)"
            " { print \"$_\"}' file";
stream = popen(cmd.c_str(),"r");
```